# Model update recreates directives

Tags: angularjs

I have problem with table and `ng-repeat`. I see that every change of model re-creates directives used inside ng-repeat. It looks obvious now, but this is a problem when I have directive and $watch inside on model. Effect is that when model is changed, ng-repeat recreates directive and $watch inside directive never see changes inside model.

http://jsfiddle.net/8w6e6245/

I need this directive to blink cell when its property change.
I can handle this probably by moving logic from directive to controller but maybe there is something wrong in that table approach where every model update iterate with ng-repeat again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix issue where angular recreates every time DOM, needs to add `track by $index`

http://jsfiddle.net/zrbxgn06/